# Can't boot into Linux Mint partition after gnome 3 uninstall

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint

I have a partition for Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.3 rosa installed and I decided to install Gnome 3. I decided 5 minutes into it that I did not like it, so I removed it using the command

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-session
```

after running that command, I ignorantly figured I was finished and rebooted. Now it displays the mint logo and stays there, then eventually displays "Keys: Continue to wait, or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery" at the top left, but none of these keys do anything.

I've tried booting into recovery holding shift which does nothing, most likely since it is a partition. none of the function keys do anything aside from toggling the boot screen to appear and disappear, and when I try to do ctrl-alt-f2/f3, it opens up a console and logs into my user but displays many of this type of error code

```
[ xxx.xxxxxx] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCI e Bus Error: severity = Corrected, type=Pysical Layer, id=00e7(Receiver ID)
[ xxx.xxxxxx] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a117] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[ xxx.xxxxxx] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] Receiver Error
```

Aside from this, I don't know what else to try. There's no way I've found to get access to a terminal, grub, or boot into recovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite those errors coming through on the console you should be able to issue commands via a vterm (ctrl+f2-7) if you just hit enter or ctrl+l (that's a lowercase L, for clarity) you should get a bash prompt.

You could certainly try reinstalling gnome-session via that shell, just to see if that resolves the issue.. However, I hate to say it, but seeing device errors such as that is not a good sign, and often times is a sign of drive failure.

You might first try forcing a check of the filesystem at your next boot by issuing the following commands.

You'll need to be root, so

```
sudo -s
```

then create a file at the root of the filesystem called "forcefsck"

```
touch /forcefsck
```

then reboot and the OS should enforce a filesystem check at next boot.

```
reboot
```

If the check doesn't report any errors, then hooray! we can worry about restoring your OS.

Regardless, there should *definitely* be a way to restore your data. This might feel scary, but if the drive isn't completely fragged, then we should have no problem recovering your data.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to login from the console without being berated by those error messages. Once I got terminal access, I ran the command 

    `sudo apt-get install mdm`

since gnome uninstalls the mint login screen and replaces it with its own gdm. Anyways, I have it up and running now, thank you :)

Comment: Great news!! I'm glad to hear that everything works again :)